# JSON Data to Javascript Array Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, google-apps-script

I am trying to get data from a JSON file and use Javascript Code to put it into Google Spreadsheet, I did good with some part of the data but I'm stuck with the other part, where I want to match the User Id and put all the data with it on a same row,

JSON Data:

```
"m":{"414":{"a":{"0":{"c":38,"p":12812.4}, 
"4":{"c":35,"p":10559.94},"2":{"c":43,"p":35811.63},
"6":{"c":48,"p":45530}},"d":{"0":{"c":55,"p":5477.06225},
"4":{"c":694,"p":106649.473},"2":{"c":1844,"p":716733.50775000011},
"6":{"c":605,"p":324152.5875}},"i":{"0":{"c":0,"p":0},
"4":{"c":0,"p":0},"2":{"c":0,"p":0},"6":{"c":542,"p":19893.93}}},
"404":{"a":{"0":{"c":15,"p":916.182},"4":{"c":50,"p":12357},
"2":{"c":530,"p":390825.27},"6":{"c":58,"p":4841.55}},
"d":{"0":{"c":10,"p":3145.8},"4":{"c":770,"p":141876.12},
"2":{"c":4854,"p":2173966.6125000003},
"6":{"c":1973,"p":1145077.425}},"i":{"0":{"c":0,"p":0},
"4":{"c":0,"p":0},"2":{"c":0,"p":0},"6":{"c":594,"p":25444.41}}}},
```

Javascript:

```
var testUF = [];
var Uid = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc1.m);
  for (var lp2 = 0; lp2 < Uid.length; lp2++) {
    var Ua1 = doc1.m[lp2].a["0"].p;
    var Ua2 = doc1.m[lp2].a["4"].p;
    var Ua3 = doc1.m[lp2].a["2"].p;
    var Ua4 = doc1.m[lp2].a["6"].p;
    var Ud1 = doc1.m[lp2].d["0"].p;
    var Ud2 = doc1.m[lp2].d["4"].p;
    var Ud3 = doc1.m[lp2].d["2"].p;
    var Ud4 = doc1.m[lp2].d["6"].p;
    var Ui4 = doc1.m[lp2].i["6"].p;

  testUF.push([Uid,Ua1,Ua2,Ua3,Ua4,Ud1,Ud2,Ud3,Ud4,Ui4]);}
```

I am getting the Array on the Uid while Debugging, but all the other Variables don't get the data it stays Undefined. I want all the other variables to match with the Uid's and stay in the same row. I did the JSON parsing and everything.

I am asking for the first time on stackoverflow, please forgive me if I couldn't state everything properly. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: how uid variables data look like???

Comment: `["414", "404", "393", "193", "417", "117", "780", "1504", "1117", "1607", "19452", "26609", "28586", "51821"]`

It's way longer I just posted a lil part of the data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the array index for Uid properly.

Change:

`var Ua1 = doc1.m[lp2].a["0"].p;`

To:

`var Ua1 = doc1.m[Uid[lp2]].a["0"].p;`

Comment: Ah!! I see, Thank you Very Much, It solved my problem ^_^